# How to return a default value in an AsyncPipe in Angular/Ionic Observable/Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I did an async pipe using aws translate to show translated text with a promise and it works, but I need to define wether the user wants the original text, or if it wants the translation, so I added to a provider the value `isActive: boolean = false` and a `if` condition so if `isActive` is `false`, just return the default value, but I'm getting this:

```
PipelinePage.html:87 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'In Progress' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

[image]

translate.pipe.ts //Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateProvider } from "../../providers/translate/translate";

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(public translate: TranslateProvider){}

  transform(value: string, ...args) {
      if(this.translate.isActive === true){
        const params = {
          Text: value,
          SourceLanguageCode: "en",
          TargetLanguageCode: "es"
        };
        let actionPromise = this.translate.translator.translateText(params).promise();
        return actionPromise.then((data) => {
          return data.TranslatedText;
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }

}
```

translate.ts //Provider

```
export class TranslateProvider {
  ...
  public isActive: boolean = false;
  ...
}
```

On template:

```
translate | async
```

How can I return the default value if isActive is false? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming the current code actually works. I think you just need to add an else statement at the out most level and return value. if(this.translate.isActive === true){ // your current code}else{return value}

Comment: I think that the if condition right now is at the highest level. I think the problem is that | async is gets still waiting for a type promise in this case. But I still don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async` pipe expects a Promise or an Observable as input, but when isActive is `false` you just a return a string.

So in your TranslatePipe instead of using `return value;` you need to return a Promise with value as content.

You could also try to mark the entire transform method as `async`, which should automatically put any return value in a Promise. So it should look something like this:

```
  async transform(value: string, ...args) {
      if(this.translate.isActive === true){
        const params = {
          Text: value,
          SourceLanguageCode: "en",
          TargetLanguageCode: "es"
        };
        let actionPromise = this.translate.translator.translateText(params).promise();
        actionPromise.then((data) => { // <- Dont return the promise but return in the promise (you could also use await)
          return data.TranslatedText;
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }
```